# How can i make `printfn "%A"` print full complex structures?

Tags: f#

When I print a complex stuctured value via `printfn "%A"` the output is truncated as in the example below.

for [fsi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/interactive.interactivesession-class-[fsharp]) there are some options (ie `fsi.PrintLength <- System.Int32.MaxValue`) to change this behavior.

How do i get the full structure in a simple console App?

`seq
  [[adspath, {name = "adspath";
 typ = "System.String";
 count = 1;
 value =
  "GC://...";}];
   [c, {name = "c";
 typ = "System.String";
 count = 1;
 value = "DE";}];
   [cn, {name = "cn";
 typ = "System.String";
 count = 1;
 value = "I....";}];
   [co, {name = "co";
 typ = "System.String";
 count = 1;
 value = "DE";}]; ...]`

Comment: Have you tried materializing the `seq` with `Seq.toList` or Array first and then printing it?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Thanks :>

Answer (score 3):

As i cannot delete the question here is the answer. The Problem was that the sequence was not materalised. In my case I had a value of type `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,<T>>`

```
v 
|> Seq.toList
|> printfn "%A"
```

solves it.